# How to fix a pm2 error in shell_exec in php page?

Tags: php, pm2, shell-exec

I would like to start and stop my pm2 application via my site, including

```
shell_exec(" pm2 start 0 ");
```

for example. It does not return me an error but the message of welcome what I do not want. In the terminal it sends me a number, which I want but not on PHP.

Welcome message : https://pastebin.com/raw/R3t4AJux

Translate with Google translation from French.

Comment: Are you running the code and terminal as the same user? In the same working directory?

Comment: Yes in my terminal this work, but the same command in shell_exec() don't work.
I have my heberger site on my raspberry and my Node.js application too (bot discord)

Comment: If you are using the terminal as the user `pi` and the http server runs the PHP code as `apache` or `www-data`, they can't access the same PM2 setup. You need to make sure that when you run `pm2 start 0` from the terminal as the same user, from the same working directory, it works.